# Run Android instrumented tests fail

Tags: android, android-studio, automated-tests

I tried to implement some unit and instrumented tests for my Android application (Java), my unit tests is working fine but  instrumented tests are failing:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@LargeTest
public class ExampleInstrumentedTest {
    @Rule
    public IntentsTestRule<MainActivity> mActivityRule = new IntentsTestRule<>(MainActivity.class);


    @Test
    public void checkIfCategoriesIsNotEmpty() {
        onView(withId(R.id.header_left_layout)).perform(click());
        onView(withId(R.id.list_view)).check(new ViewAssertion() {
            @Override
            public void check(View view, NoMatchingViewException noViewFoundException) {
                ListView list_categories = (ListView) view;
                ListAdapter adapter = list_categories.getAdapter();
                Assert.assertTrue(adapter.getCount() > 0);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

When I try to run my test I got this error :

```
"Run Android instrumented tests using Gradle" option was ignored because this module type is not supported yet.
```

My Implementations in build.config file are :

```
 // UNIT TEST
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testImplementation 'org.hamcrest:java-hamcrest:2.0.0.0'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.7.1'

    // INSTRUMENTED TEST
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-intents:3.4.0'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the solution is to exclude module: **protobuf-lite** :

```
 androidTestImplementation('androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.4.0') {
        exclude module: "protobuf-lite"
    }
```

Comment: Why is this the solution? Is protobuf-lite bad for instrumented tests?

Comment: It's not bad but there's just a conflict as I understand

Comment: I don't have protobuf-lite on the dependency graph with `espresso-contrib:3.3.0`, so this cannot be the only solution.

Answer (score 28):

I just ran into this problem, too. I found the solution in the [Android Studio Bumblebee 2021.1.1 release notes](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/past-releases?hl=hu-hu#bumblebee-unified-test-runner) under the "Android testing" section.

It basically amounts to unchecking the box next to **Run Android instrumented tests using Gradle** in the testing settings. This worked for me.

[image: Testing settings Android Studio]

Comment: Thanks, Ben, an additional screenshot would be a quick +1

Comment: Although this prevented the error message, no test actually ran in my case.  Not even an error message, it just simply did nothing.  The Test Results panel shows the `adb shell` command to run the test but I saw nothing run on the emulator and no results in the Test Results panel.

Comment: I ran into the same issue as @MichaelOsofsky and it turned out to be the application crashing. Check logcat and you should see a stack trace

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/test/test-in-android-studio#disable-utp)

[Disable the unified Gradle test runner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOvvz.png)

> By default Android Studio Bumblebee uses Gradle to run its instrumentation tests. If you're experiencing issues, you can disable this behavior as follows:

```
Select File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Testing (or Android Studio > Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment > Testing on MacOS.)
Uncheck the box next to Run Android instrumented tests using Gradle and click OK.
```

So you can just disable the unified Gradle test runner.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue was that I was running on Xiaomi Redmi note 7. Once I switched to the emulator. everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add

```
testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
```

Under `defaultConfig` inside the `build.gradle` module file.

Comment: This is already present in the build.greadle file.