# "Run Android instrumented tests using Gradle" option was ignored because this module type is not supported yet. in android testing

Tags: android, kotlin, testing

"Run Android instrumented tests using Gradle" option was ignored because this module type is not supported yet.
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wL1WG.png)

Comment: This solution helped in my case
https://stackoverflow.com/a/71864048/19314886