# my android instromented tests have no results

Tags: android, gradle, junit, android-testing, gradle-android-test-plugi

I am trying to run instrumented tests for my fragments and appears nothing works
the result shows nothing no pass no errors nothing

like this answer :[answer link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71864048/15828912)

I tried unchecking the run instrumented test with Gradle

put the result is nothing :
[tests result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLNUs.png)

and when checking it : throws exception
"Run Android instrumented tests using Gradle" option was ignored because this module type is not supported yet.
"
and yet no results
[test results2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dob5J.png)

my project gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    ext.kotlinVersion = '1.3.72'
    ext.navigationVersion = '2.4.1'

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion"
        classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$navigationVersion"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
ext {
    // Sdk and tools
    // Support library and architecture components support minSdk 14 and above.
    minSdkVersion = 21
    targetSdkVersion = 30
    compileSdkVersion = 31

    // App dependencies
    androidXVersion = '1.0.0'
    androidXAnnotations = '1.0.1'
    androidXLegacySupport = '1.0.0'
    appCompatVersion = '1.2.0'
    archLifecycleVersion = '2.2.0'
    cardVersion = '1.0.0'
    materialVersion = '1.1.0'
    fragmentVersion = '1.1.0-alpha07'
    recyclerViewVersion = '1.1.0'
    mockitoVersion = '2.8.9'
    constraintVersion = '2.0.0-rc1'
    dexMakerVersion = '2.12.1'
    coroutinesVersion = '1.2.1'
    roomVersion = '2.4.2'
    koinVersion = '2.0.1'
    truthVersion = '0.44'
    junitVersion = '4.12'
    androidXTestCoreVersion = '1.2.0-beta01'
    robolectricVersion = '4.3-beta-1'
    androidXTestExtKotlinRunnerVersion = '1.1.1'
    archTestingVersion = '2.0.0'
    playServicesVersion = '17.0.0'
    hamcrestVersion = '1.3'
    androidXTestRulesVersion = '1.2.0-beta01'
    espressoVersion = '3.2.0'

}
```

app gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin"


android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.compileSdkVersion

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mostafan3ma.android.pcm_helper10"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }


    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    testOptions.unitTests {
        includeAndroidResources = true
        returnDefaultValues = true
    }

    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
        dataBinding = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$appCompatVersion"
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:$materialVersion"
    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:$constraintVersion"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$navigationVersion"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$navigationVersion"
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    implementation "androidx.annotation:annotation:$androidXAnnotations"


    kapt "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$archLifecycleVersion"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$archLifecycleVersion"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$archLifecycleVersion"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$archLifecycleVersion"


    //Room dependencies
    implementation("androidx.room:room-runtime:$roomVersion")
    annotationProcessor("androidx.room:room-compiler:$roomVersion")
    kapt("androidx.room:room-compiler:$roomVersion")
    implementation("androidx.room:room-ktx:$roomVersion")

    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'


    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:$playServicesVersion"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:$playServicesVersion"


    //floating action button
    implementation 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.10.1'

    //xls files api
    implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi:3.17'


    // Dependencies for local unit tests
    testImplementation "junit:junit:$junitVersion"
    testImplementation "androidx.test:core-ktx:$androidXTestCoreVersion"
    testImplementation "org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:$hamcrestVersion"

    // Dependencies for Android instrumented unit tests
    androidTestImplementation "junit:junit:$junitVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-core:$mockitoVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "com.linkedin.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:$dexMakerVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-test:$coroutinesVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:$archTestingVersion"

//Robolectric and AndroidX test Dependencies
    testImplementation "androidx.test:core-ktx:$androidXTestCoreVersion"
    testImplementation "org.robolectric:robolectric:$robolectricVersion"
    "androidx.test.ext:junit-ktx:$androidXTestExtKotlinRunnerVersion"
    testImplementation "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:$archTestingVersion"
    testImplementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-test:$coroutinesVersion"



    // AndroidX Test - Instrumented testing
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit:$androidXTestExtKotlinRunnerVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:$espressoVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:$espressoVersion"
    implementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-idling-resource:$espressoVersion"

    implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-testing:$fragmentVersion"
    implementation "androidx.test:core:$androidXTestCoreVersion"


}
```

I am using ServiceLocater to inject repository into fragments

ServiceLocater.kt:

```
package com.mostafan3ma.android.pcm_helper10

import android.content.Context
import androidx.annotation.VisibleForTesting
import androidx.room.Room
import com.mostafan3ma.android.pcm_helper10.data.source.DefaultLocalDataSource
import com.mostafan3ma.android.pcm_helper10.data.source.LocalDataSource.LocalDataSource
import com.mostafan3ma.android.pcm_helper10.data.source.PipeLinesRepository
import com.mostafan3ma.android.pcm_helper10.data.source.database.LineDataBase
import kotlinx.coroutines.runBlocking

object ServiceLocator {
    private var dataBase:LineDataBase?=null

    @Volatile
    var pipeLinesRepository: PipeLinesRepository?=null
    @VisibleForTesting set
    private val lock=Any()


    fun provideRepository(context: Context):PipeLinesRepository{
        synchronized(this){
            return pipeLinesRepository?:createPipeLineRepository(context)
        }

    }

    private fun createPipeLineRepository(context: Context): PipeLinesRepository {
        val newRepo=PipeLinesRepository(createLocalDataSource(context))
        pipeLinesRepository=newRepo
        return newRepo
    }

    private fun createLocalDataSource(context: Context): DefaultLocalDataSource {
        val dataBase= dataBase?:createDatabase(context)
        return LocalDataSource(dataBase.lineDao())
    }

    private fun createDatabase(context: Context): LineDataBase {
        val result= Room.databaseBuilder(
            context.applicationContext,
            LineDataBase::class.java,
            "Lins"
        ).fallbackToDestructiveMigration().build()
        dataBase=result

        return result
    }

    @VisibleForTesting
    fun resetRepo(){
        synchronized(lock){
            runBlocking {
                pipeLinesRepository?.clearAllLines()
            }
            dataBase?.apply {
                clearAllTables()
                close()
            }
            dataBase=null
            pipeLinesRepository=null
        }
    }




}
```

and the test class for one of the fragments :

```
package com.mostafan3ma.android.pcm_helper10.lines

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.arch.core.executor.testing.InstantTaskExecutorRule
import androidx.fragment.app.testing.launchFragmentInContainer
import androidx.test.espresso.Espresso.onView
import androidx.test.espresso.assertion.ViewAssertions.matches
import androidx.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.isDisplayed
import androidx.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withId
import androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4
import androidx.test.filters.MediumTest
import com.mostafan3ma.android.pcm_helper10.R
import com.mostafan3ma.android.pcm_helper10.ServiceLocator
import com.mostafan3ma.android.pcm_helper10.Utils.FakeDataSource
import com.mostafan3ma.android.pcm_helper10.Utils.MainCoroutineRule
import com.mostafan3ma.android.pcm_helper10.data.source.PipeLinesRepository
import com.mostafan3ma.android.pcm_helper10.data.source.database.DamagePoint
import com.mostafan3ma.android.pcm_helper10.data.source.database.PipeLine
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
import kotlinx.coroutines.test.runBlockingTest
import org.junit.Assert.*

import org.junit.After
import org.junit.Before
import org.junit.Rule
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith

@MediumTest
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
class MainLinesFragmentTest {
 private val initList = mutableListOf<PipeLine>(
     PipeLine(
         id = 1,
         name = "line1",
         ogm = "1",
         length = "1000",
         type = "Water",
         i_start = "1000",
         i_end = "10",
         start_point_x = "511511",
         start_point_y = "3591511",
         end_point_x = "511511",
         end_point_y = "3591511",
         start_work_date = "2/5/2022",
         end_work_date = "3/5/2022",
         work_team = "Mostafa Nema 1",
         input = "1A",
         extra_note = "note1",
         points = mutableListOf<DamagePoint>(
             DamagePoint(
                 no = 1, db = "11", depth = "1.1",
                 current1 = "111", current2 = "122",
                 gps_x = "511511", gps_y = "35911511",
                 note = "point note1", is_point = true
             ),
             DamagePoint(
                 no = 2, db = "22", depth = "2.2",
                 current1 = "211", current2 = "222",
                 gps_x = "511511", gps_y = "35911511",
                 note = "point note2", is_point = true
             ),
             DamagePoint(is_point = false),
             DamagePoint(
                 no = 3, db = "33", depth = "3.1",
                 current1 = "311", current2 = "322",
                 gps_x = "511511", gps_y = "35911511",
                 note = "point note3", is_point = true
             )
         )
     ),
     PipeLine(
         id = 2,
         name = "line2",
         ogm = "2",
         length = "2000",
         type = "oil",
         i_start = "2000",
         i_end = "20",
         start_point_x = "522522",
         start_point_y = "3591522",
         end_point_x = "522522",
         end_point_y = "3591522",
         start_work_date = "2/5/2022",
         end_work_date = "3/5/2022",
         work_team = "Mostafa Nema 2",
         input = "2A",
         extra_note = "note2",
         points = mutableListOf<DamagePoint>(
             DamagePoint(
                 no = 1, db = "11", depth = "1.1",
                 current1 = "111", current2 = "122",
                 gps_x = "511511", gps_y = "35911511",
                 note = "point note1", is_point = true
             )
         )
     )


 )
 private lateinit var localDataSource: FakeDataSource
 private lateinit var repository: PipeLinesRepository

 @get:Rule
 val mainCoroutineRule = MainCoroutineRule()

 @get:Rule
 var instantExecutorRule= InstantTaskExecutorRule()

 @Before
 fun setUp() {
     localDataSource = FakeDataSource(initList)
     repository=PipeLinesRepository(localDataSource,Dispatchers.Main)
     ServiceLocator.pipeLinesRepository=repository
 }

 @After
 fun tearDown() {
     ServiceLocator.resetRepo()
 }


 @Test
 fun displayFragment_TwoPipeInList()=mainCoroutineRule.runBlockingTest {
 launchFragmentInContainer<MainLinesFragment>(Bundle(), R.style.Theme_Pcmhelper10)
     onView(withId(R.id.fab_add_line)).check(matches(isDisplayed()))


 }




}
```

and I got this exception which didn't understand !!

```
2022-06-07 00:12:34.950 6305-6325/com.mostafan3ma.android.pcm_helper10 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Instr: androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
Process: com.mostafan3ma.android.pcm_helper10, PID: 6305
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method shouldWaitForActivitiesToComplete()Z in class Landroidx/test/runner/AndroidJUnitRunner; or its super classes (declaration of 'androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner' appears in /data/app/~~4CMeGrOsgkmvqLHECyOCZw==/com.mostafan3ma.android.pcm_helper10.test-N5A3R_1QMgwrtEkdIr0X8Q==/base.apk)
    at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.addListenersLegacyOrder(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:490)
    at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.addListeners(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:471)
    at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:443)
    at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2248)
```

Answer (score 0):

REPLACE

```
testImplementation "org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:$hamcrestVersion"
```

WITH

```
testImplementation 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest:2.2'
testImplementation 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:2.2'
```